# How to create user of elastic using flask

Tags: elasticsearch, flask, kibana

I want to create a **user** | **role** | **privilege** of `elastic` using `API` in `flask`
[Documentation for creating user](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/security-api-put-user.html) provided an example

it's working fine in `elastic` **Dev Tools**
[image: Creating new user using in console]
but how can I convert it into a `python` **POST** request?

**My Code**

```
from flask import Flask, request, jsonify, render_template
from elasticsearch import Elasticsearch

CLOUD_ID = "myfirstdeployment:XXX"
ELASTIC_PASS = 'XXX'
ELASTIC_USER = 'XXX'

client = Elasticsearch(cloud_id=CLOUD_ID, basic_auth=(ELASTIC_USER, ELASTIC_PASS))

app = Flask(__name__)
import requests
from requests.structures import CaseInsensitiveDict

@app.route('/get')
def getting():
    data = client.search(index="kibana_sample_data_ecommerce", body={"query" :{"match_all":{}}})
    return f'{[x["_source"]["category"] for x in data["hits"]["hits"]]}'

es = Elasticsearch(hosts="https://localhost:9200", basic_auth=('elastic', 'zoU_Ec8JjbPnQNG4b8kY'), verify_certs=False)
@app.route('/local')
def local():
    return f'{es.info()}'

@app.route('/users')
def getAllUser():
    uri = 'https://localhost:9200/_security/user/'
    es = Elasticsearch(hosts=uri, basic_auth=('elastic', 'zoU_Ec8JjbPnQNG4b8kY'), ca_certs="872ee6c0879fc0cfe73054c3ba7afb5902dbb171a2c215af35a5faab1206b924", verify_certs=False)
    return f'{es.info()}'


@app.route('/users/<name>')
def getSingleUser(name):
    try:
        uri = f'https://localhost:9200/_security/user/{name}'
        es = Elasticsearch(hosts=uri, basic_auth=('elastic', 'zoU_Ec8JjbPnQNG4b8kY'), ca_certs="872ee6c0879fc0cfe73054c3ba7afb5902dbb171a2c215af35a5faab1206b924", verify_certs=False)
        return f'{es.info()}'
    except:
        content = {'error':'User Not Found'}
        return content, 404

@app.route('/create-new-user', methods=['GET','POST'])
def createUser():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        username = request.form.get('username')
        password = request.form.get('password')
        email = request.form.get('email')
        fullname = request.form.get('fullname')
        role = request.form.getlist('role')
        body ={"password":password, "username":username, "email":email, "fullname":fullname, "role":role}
        try:
            uri = f'https://localhost:9200/_security/user/{username}'
            es = Elasticsearch(hosts=uri, basic_auth=('elastic', 'zoU_Ec8JjbPnQNG4b8kY'), ca_certs="872ee6c0879fc0cfe73054c3ba7afb5902dbb171a2c215af35a5faab1206b924", verify_certs=False)
            return f'{es.info()}'
        except:
            content = {'error':'something went wrong'}
            return content, 501
    return render_template('add_user.html')

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

when I create a user from **Stack Management > Security > User > Create**
`POST` request send to `security/user/new_user_username`
`post data` = `{password=password, username=username, email=email, role=[], fullname=fullname`

Comment: Hi, could you first of all, provide your code as a snipped not a picture., Could you also tell us what issu your are facing ? what error / logs do you have when you perform the request

Comment: Also I believe the python lib has [put_user](https://elasticsearch-py.readthedocs.io/en/v8.3.3/api.html#elasticsearch.client.SecurityClient.put_user)

Comment: @Paulo I edited, I am not getting any error I just don't understand how to pass `data` to this `localhost:9200/_security/user/{name}` with `basic authentication`

Comment: yes I think `requests` module have some method like `post` `put` but how can I pass `new user` data to `elastic` without `auth` and `it's instance` (example = getSingleUser and getAllUser)

Comment: Ahh what you have just done with `es = Elasticsearch(...)` is declaring the client. Now you can use the client `es.put_user()` which will perform the request

Comment: @Paulo no such method `put_user()` available on `es`

Comment: Yes but in the python lib it is available ... look at the documentation I sent you https://elasticsearch-py.readthedocs.io/en/v8.3.3/api.html#elasticsearch.client.SecurityClient.put_user

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first Thanks to **[Paulo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4534923/paulo)** 
Using [put_user()](https://elasticsearch-py.readthedocs.io/en/v8.3.3/api.html#elasticsearch.client.SecurityClient.put_user) method we can easily create `user`

[image: Image For Creating a user in elastic]

`username`, `password` & `email` fields are mandatory when creating a `user` using  `API`

```
@app.route('/create-new-user', methods=['GET','POST'])
def createUser():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        username = request.form.get('username')
        password = request.form.get('password')
        email = request.form.get('email')
        fullname = request.form.get('fullname')
        roles = request.form.getlist('role')
        body ={"password":password, "username":username, "email":email, "fullname":fullname, "roles":roles}
        try:
            client = Elasticsearch(hosts=https://localhost:9200/, basic_auth=(ELASTIC_USERNAME, ELASTIC_PASSWORD), ca_certs=CERTIFICATE, verify_certs=False)
            es = SecurityClient(client)
            es.put_user(**body)
            return {'message':'User created'}, 201
        except:
            return {'message':'something went wrong'}, 501
    return render_template('add_user.html')
```

**Remember** to pass `keyword args` of `roles` in `put_user`

**Edited** if someone experimenting can also try [perform_request](https://elasticsearch-py.readthedocs.io/en/7.x/connection.html?highlight=perform_request#elasticsearch.Transport.perform_request)

**Edited 2** Simple and better solution

```
body ={"password":password, "username":username, "email":email, "full_name":fullname, 'enabled':True, 'roles':role}
uri = f'https://localhost:9200/'
client = Elasticsearch(hosts=uri, basic_auth=(ELASTIC_USER, ELASTIC_PASS), ca_certs=CERTIFICATE, verify_certs=False)
client.perform_request(body=body, method='POST', path=f'/_security/user/{username}', headers={'content-type':'application/json', 'accept':'application/json'})
```

Comment: for method 2 , you didnt use SecurityClient ? Is that the same? May i Know whats the use of SecurityClient in Method (1)?

Comment: @ManManYu `SecurityClient` will allow you to work with API relevant to `users`, `tokens`, `roles`, `privileges` etc it's a cleaner way, as compared to `method 2` I need to know the exact `path` and `header` for that